# Rails post delete functionality giving template error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to have a link to delete a certain reservation from the database. This is my solution but it keeps giving Template Error. It shouldn't render the view but it is.

```
def delete
  @current = Reservations.find(params['reservations']['id'])
  respond_to do |format|
    if current_user

        if @current.user_id == current_user.id
            @current.destroy
            format.html { redirect_to :back }
        else
            format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        end
    else
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    end
  end
end
```

My routes file

```
post "reservations/delete", to: 'reservations#delete', as: 'delete_reservation'
```

My view that includes the delete link:

```
<%= form_for item, :url => {:controller => 'reservations', :action => 'delete'}, :method => 'post' do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => item.id %>

  <%= f.submit "Delete", :class =>'btn btn-danger btn-small' %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: always have a look at your logs when running into issues. they are there to help you debug an application. always keep a terminal window open and run `tail -f log/development.log` to screen incoming requests. what are the params? what is the content type? is it the right controller? etc

Comment: Try with :method => 'delete' in your form_for tag.

Comment: Why do you delete with `POST` HTTP method instead of `DELETE` method, which is made for this kind of action?